# Логическое AND в регулярных выражениях

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки, pandas, dataframe

Если `OR` это символ **|**, например:

```
.str.contains(r"123|abc", case=False, regex=True)
# логическое или ->^
```

В данном примере мы ищем вхождение `123` или `abc`, а нужно чтобы в строку входило `123` и `abc` одновременно.

Какой символ будет для `AND`?

Comment: я думаю `&` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
ser.str.contains(r"(?:123.*abc|abc.*123)", case=False)
```

или так:

```
(ser.str.contains(r"123", case=False, regex=False)
 & 
 ser.str.contains(r"abc", case=False, regex=False))
```

Comment: @Jimmy, второй вариант может оказаться быстрее ;)